# gradle: copy zip to mule apps

Tags: gradle, mule, mule-studio, mule-component, gradle-plugin

I’m using Gradle 2.3. When building my mule 3.7 zip artifact, assuming all the tests pass and assembly of the war is successful, I’d like to copy my ZIP to my local $MULE_HOME/apps directory. So I have defined this in my build.gradle script:

```
 task deploylocal() << {
    println "Copy from ${buildDir} into $System.env.MULE_HOME/apps"
    copy{
      from "${buildDir}"
      into "$System.env.MULE_HOME/apps"
      include '*.zip'
    }
  }
```

Then, execute the gradle command:

```
gradle build deploylocal
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using `mule-gradle-plugin`. Refer "Special Features" section.

> The build can be configured to deploy the resulting artifact on a mule
> standalone server:
>
> mule.installPath = '/path/to/mule/home'
>
> Alternatively it can be configured through the MULE_HOME environment variable.
> Finally to deploy:
>
> $ gradle deployLocally

More details can be found at mule-gradle-plugin [documentation](https://github.com/mulesoft-labs/mule-gradle-plugin)

Hope this helps.